# Getting a Script Error Every Time I Click a Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, anchor

I have everything working perfectly on my site, but for some reason, I get an error message in console whenever I click a link anywhere on my site.  The error has to do with this line of coding here:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.navbar a, .scroll a, .smoothscroll a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 850,'easeInOutExpo');

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

And the error I am getting is this:

"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'top': object is null or undefined 
custom.min.js, line 6 character 197"

The exact code it is highlighting is this part of the above code:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
}, 850,'easeInOutExpo')
```

All I know is that when I remove the above code, my scroll-to links stop working on pages such as these:

http://www.northtownsremodeling.com/things-to-know.php

You can see the popup error happen and stay in the console easily by going to a page with a filter like this:

http://www.northtownsremodeling.com/bathroom/

And clicking one of the filter buttons.

Ultimately, I am trying to make it so my scroll-to setting still works, but not have that error come up anymore.  I made this script a long time ago, and I'm really confused as to what could be causing this error when everything is functioning perfectly otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `console.log($($anchor.attr('href')))` output the desired value at first place?

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to have `.navbar a, or .scroll a` anywhere, I only have div classes which have .smoothscroll, and <a>'s which call out to #'s which it smoothscrolls to.  I just deleted the two above, and still get the error, the error is pointed at the ".top" attribute, saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that the code which gives error is for scrolling to predefined div, and you have its id (of target div) in hashtag of url (href attribute of clicked link).

This is problem when you click "normal" link, because it does not contain hashtag which is id of element existing on page, so `$($anchor.attr('href'))` gives empty array, because there is no such element which can be selected with i.e. `$("http://www.northtownsremodeling.com/alliances.php")`, so, in that case offset() is undefined and gives you an error.

To fix this, replace:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
}, 850,'easeInOutExpo');
```

with:

```
// get target div to scroll to
var target = $($anchor.attr('href'));
// if target is valid, scroll to
if(target && target.offset()){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 850,'easeInOutExpo');
}
```

Comment: Okay, that worked... Although now I'm extremely confused as to what the code I have is even doing, and what code I have in there that's unnecessary.. What info do you need to to understand what's going on?

Comment: Okay, thanks so much, this worked perfectly.  Am I doing something wrong this way though?  I feel like I'm kind of ghetto rigging it with your solution, I feel like I'm just simply using the wrong code for what I'm trying to do.  Put your solution in and it works great though, thanks so much!

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Thanks for the response, I'm just a bit confused exactly what you mean by that.  What do you mean by "specify your selectors to bind event only to navigation links" exactly? you made it ".nav a" but isn't that the same concept as ".smoothscroll a" which I am currently using? -Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is the same concept, but you use `.smoothscroll a` selector, that means "a" inside elem which has _smoothscroll_ class. So if there is also an _a_ which is not for scroll but for navigation to another page, there is your error. You could add a class to all anchor elements which are scroll navigators, so you can filter them out in click selector. Basically, you need to avoid handling click events of anchor elements which do not have scroll target.

Comment: Ohhh okay, so pretty much I messed up my usage of throwing in .smoothscroll as a class everywhere because whenever I have a legitimate link within a smoothscroll class, it does the function when I didn't want it to do it.  I just made the mistake of putting smoothscroll absolutely everywhere, thinking that nothing was wrong with that, but there actually is an issue with doing that..  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: EDIT: So is there any way to just call out to a specific class within an `<a>` attribute?

  So like instead of going `<div class="smoothscroll"><a href="#test"></a></div>` That I can instead just go: `<a href="#test" class="smoothscroll"></a>` and it'd work for that particular link?  Or do I HAVE to have a `<span/div class="smoothscroll"></span/div>` wherever I want to use smoothscroll?  Thanks again!

Comment: No. You can use `<a href="#test" class="smoothscroll"></a>`, just change your selector from `$(".smoothscroll a")` to `$("a.smoothscroll")`

Comment: I just looked into it a bit, and found the code: `.smoothscroll a[href^="#"]` is that a good replacement?  I mean it makes sense now that it's only targeting links which have a # (which are the only links which are gonna scroll anyways).  Thanks again!

Comment: Is that a good replacement? You can answer it yourself: Does it work (in all browsers you are building for)? Is it readable to you? (If not, put a comment which explains what it does for next developer) Is it fast enough for you?

Comment: Well the site only has to work in IE8 and later + all other major browsers, so I should be good then.  Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SWgYD/

I think it is because `href` attributes does not contain right selectors. If a link accords to a block with id `nav`, then link's `href` attibute should be `#nav`.

You should bind the event handler only to navigation links.